# how to check dynamically added tealium utag submitted or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, analytics, tealium

My web page I am using Tealium for tracking visitors details. It is a AJAX based site. So I am dynamically passing utag on click event.

```
$("#test").click(function() {
  var utag_data={
  site_region:"USA",
  site_currency:"USD",
  selected_language:"en_US",
  page_name:"test1",
  page_type:"test2",
  product_sku:  ["1506742"],
  product_name: ["test3"], 
};
utag.view(utag_data);
});
```

Is there any way to test my data is populating correctly or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check out what the tag is generating by using the console log function.

```
$("#test").click(function() {
  var utag_data={
  site_region:"USA",
  site_currency:"USD",
  selected_language:"en_US",
  page_name:"test1",
  page_type:"test2",
  product_sku:  ["1506742"],
  product_name: ["test3"], 
};
console.log(utag_data)
utag.view(utag_data);
});
```

This code should help you see the object being created and it's values. You can then just compare it to what the API expects.

Comment: yes.. I have checked by using console.log and it is working fine

Comment: In that case you're good to go. Are you having any issues with the AJAX data being passed?

Comment: how can I confirm that my data is submitted in Tealium or not?

Comment: Do you have a backend account panel you can verify your test data against?

Answer (score 1):

To make sure that Tealium is working as expected you can turn on [debug mode](https://docs.tealium.com/platforms/javascript/debugging/#debug-mode) and you will see all the Tealium console logs. You can then filter console logs for `trigger: view` to see if your click event is going through.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UDO Debugger extension to check if the data is pushed